# Display Toast from within static method in Android

Tags: android, methods, static, toast

I wish to display a toast to the screen when a certain condition is met within my static method as shown below:

```
public static void setAuth(String a) {

    String[] nameparts1;

    if (a.trim().isEmpty()) {
        author = "Author's Name";
        firstinit1 = "Initial";
        surname1 = "Surname";
    }

    if (a == 'X') {
        Toast ifx = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter name in correct format.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        ifx.show();
    }
}
```

However this gives me the error: 'Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getApplicationContext() from the type ContextWrapper'.

Hopefully I have provided enough information here. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: sort of strange that this is static, no?  You probably shouldn't be doing that: it implies you're relying on Android not to kill your app.  Once it's dead your static references will be dead and gone.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Pass the context in as a parameter (in the call, use getApplicationContext() as the input) and in the static function, use context:

```
public static void setAuth(String a, Context context) {
...
Toast ifx = Toast.makeText(context, "Please enter name in correct format.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
...
}
```

And in the function call

```
setAuth("Some String",getApplicationContext());
```

Comment: here i see the error: non-static method getapplicationcontext() cannot be referenced from a static context

Answer (score 1):

you must pass the context as a parameter to your method

```
public static void dialog(boolean value, Context context) {
        if (value) {
 Toast.makeText(context, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
}
```